# Cropper rotating incorrect image in the array of images

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, cropperjs

I'm trying to navigate between multiple arrays of images which I want to render and rotate. Currently, while when I'm changing the selection from `q-select`, the images are rendering correctly, and if I print out the `index` in `rotateImage` it shows correct values for index, however when I click Rotate button on that index, it rotates the incorrect image in the array.
 **Note** that when the app starts, it works correctly and rotates the correct image, however this issue of rotation of incorrect image in the array starts to happen once I start changing the selection in `q-select`.

```
   <q-select
          dense
          borderless
          filled
          style="max-width: 35%"
          v-model="selection"
          :options="Options"
        />
    <div
         v-for="(imageData, index) in selection"
              :key="`${selection}-${index}`"
            >
              <vue-cropper
                ref="cropper"
                :src="imageData"
                 ..
                :cropBoxMovable="false"
                :zoomable="true"
                @cropend=".."
              />
              <q-menu touch-position>
                <q-list style="min-width: 100px">
                  <q-item @click="rotateImage(index)" clickable v-close-popup>
                    <q-item-section>Rotate</q-item-section>
                  </q-item>
                  <q-item clickable v-close-popup>
                    <q-item-section>Close</q-item-section>
                  </q-item>
                </q-list>
              </q-menu>
            </div>

..
<script setup>
..
const rotateImage = async (index) => {
  const cropperInstance = cropper.value[index];
  cropperInstance.clear();
  cropperInstance.initCrop();
  cropperInstance.rotate(90);

};
```

Comment: Would you be able to create a *runnable* [mcve]? Use codensandbox.io or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `ref` for a `v-for` is not guaranteed to stay in the same order as the array used by the `v-for`.

Easy approach is to add a uuid to each value in the array and then apply it to a component as a `data-` attribute. You can then use the uuid in the handler to search the instances in the `ref` for the correct one.

See last paragraph of this section of the docs:

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for